# Converting ObservableCollection to List?

Tags: c#, observablecollection

How does one convert an `ObservableCollection` to a `List` of the held objects?

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Depending on the type of object in the `ObservableCollection`... I'll assume it's an `int` for this example:

```
IEnumerable<int> obsCollection = (IEnumerable<int>)GetCollection();
var list = new List<int>(obsCollection);
```

Comment: @Matthew, I rewrote it without the unnecessary explicit cast - change it back if you don't like it this way.

Comment: @280Z28: According to the original question, he's getting an object as his collection, in which case a cast is needed somewhere.

Comment: why cast it to IEnumerable<>? Couldn't I just past it in the new List<>(here)?

Comment: You indicated in your question that you were recieving it as an `object`. If you are actually recieving it as an `ObservableCollection`, then yes, the cast is unnecessary.

Comment: That said, yes, you can do it on one line. I just dislike really long lines in code snippets here (scrolling sucks, everyone knows that).

Answer (score 86):

Just need to add the namespace `using System.Linq;`

and use the method `ToList()` in the ObservableCollection object

Comment: I wish I would remember this the next time I run into this very issue.

Answer (score 27):

Given that `ObservableCollection<T>` implements `IEnumerable<T>` you can give it to the constructor of `List<T>`:

```
List<T> myList = new List<T>(myObservableCollection);
```

Where `T` is the type of the items in the collection.

Answer (score 5):

`ObservableCollection` implements `IList<T>`, so you should be able to use `ToList()` on it.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342261.aspx

Comment: Only in 3.5 with LINQ, I'd argue just creating the list yourself from an IEnumerable is easier. This still involves a cast if you've only got an object.

Answer (score 2):

The Items property returns an IList.  [See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132435.aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132435.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue here is that ObservableCollection might be modified on the fly when you try to convert it to a List or use as such, so you might need to use a watchdog timer of sorts until ObservableCollection finishes